# Defining variable in isset

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my code. I try to define variable after sending one form and use it after sending another. When i do this i got "Notice: Undefined variable: variable..." I bet that's easy to fix but i'm just a beginer.

```
<form id="formOne" method="post">
<input method="post" type="submit" name="one" value="Confirm">
</form>

<form id="formTwo" method="post">
<input method="post" type="submit" name="two" value="Confirm">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['one']))
    {

        $variable="SOME STRING";
    }


    if (isset($_POST['two']))
    {

        echo $variable; 
    }

?>
```

Comment: Http is a stateless protocol. New form request means you're initiating the request cycle. you may get rid of notice by defining empty variable first but won't get the value. so use a `Session variable` which will be available for your next request

Comment: Declare $variable='' at top

Comment: In the second 'if' you are printing $variable which is defined only if the first 'if' is executed

Comment: `<input method="post"` is invalid, there is no `method` on `input`.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If `$_POST['one']` is not coming then `OR` condition will work
Otherwise it will work asusual

```
if (isset($_POST['one']) || $variable=""){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare it on the top

```
$variable="";
if (isset($_POST['one']))
```

and maybe you can use `!empty($_POST['one'])` based on your business logic

Comment: You mean like this?

<?php
$variable="";
if (!empty($_POST['one']))
 {
  $variable="SOME STRING";
 }
 
If yes it won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  $variable ='';

if (isset($_POST['one']))
    {

        $variable="SOME STRING";
    }


    if (isset($_POST['two']))
    {

        echo $variable; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work because you can't submit two forms at the same time. So when $_POST['two'] is available $variable will never have a value because $_POST['one'] was not submitted. Declaring the variable above the "if" block it will just help you get past the notice but the code will never work.

Answer (score 0):

The POST values are only sent with the following request. With the next request after that, the values are forgotten (and if there are new data, they will be stored instead). You can store them a few different ways, an example is a session - but if you want the form to be chained in order (meaning you have to submit `formOne` before you can get the value in `formTwo`), you can add a hidden input to the second form, using the value depending on the first form being sent.

Put your PHP code before your forms, then add a hidden input inside the second form where you echo the `$variable`. This variable is only set and defined with "SOME STRING" after the first form is submitted, otherwise it is `null`.

When the second form submits, it will carry over the inputs inside that form only, including the hidden field (but not any data from the first form).

```
<?php 
$variable = isset($_POST['one']) ? "SOME STRING" : null;

if (isset($_POST['two']) {
    echo $_POST['old_one'];
}
?>

<form id="formOne" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="one" value="Confirm" />
</form>

<form id="formTwo" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="old_one" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="two" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

There is no `method` attribute on `<input>` elements, only on `<form>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. It's working right now.

I use Session variable like @SaadSuri said. I leave working code if someone had similar problem.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['one']))
    {

      $_SESSION['variable']="SOME STRING";
    }


    if (isset($_POST['two']))
    {

        echo $_SESSION['variable'];
    }

?>

<form id="formOne" method="post">
<input method="post" type="submit" name="one" value="Confirm">
</form>

<form id="formTwo" method="post">
<input method="post" type="submit" name="two" value="Confirm">
</form>
```